# Npm cannot install packages with npm init

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js

I'm trying to install next js with command below:

```
 $c:/Desktop/next: npm init next-app nextjs-blog
```

Which gave me an error

```
npm ERR! Could not install from "Dahal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\14636" as it does not contain a package.json file.
```

*Note*: My Users is `C:/Users/Sunita Dahal` but it seems to be looking inside of `Dahal`. But I'm able to install global packages.
`reinstalling & cleaning cache doesnt work work me`

Here is the complete error log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'create-next-app@latest',
1 verbose cli   '--global',
1 verbose cli   '--prefix',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Sunita',
1 verbose cli   'Dahal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_npx\\14636',
1 verbose cli   '--loglevel',
1 verbose cli   'error',
1 verbose cli   '--json'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v12.16.3
4 verbose npm-session a7314bdab23f336e
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for file:Dahal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\14636 Could not install from "Dahal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\14636" as it does not contain a package.json file.
8 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/create-next-app 167ms (from cache)
9 silly pacote tag manifest for create-next-app@latest fetched in 190ms
10 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
11 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 204ms
12 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Sunita Dahal\Desktop\next\Dahal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\14636\package.json'
13 verbose cwd C:\Users\Sunita Dahal\Desktop\next
14 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
15 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "create-next-app@latest" "--global" "--prefix" "C:\\Users\\Sunita" "Dahal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_npx\\14636" "--loglevel" "error" "--json"
16 verbose node v12.16.3
17 verbose npm  v6.14.4
18 error code ENOLOCAL
19 error Could not install from "Dahal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\14636" as it does not contain a package.json file.
20 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

**SOLUTION**
Changing my cache path fixed the issue for me.
`npm config set cache C:\tmp\nodejs\npm-cache --global`
more at: https://github.com/zkat/npx/issues/146

Comment: npm i will install the package !!! npm init will install the all the modules into the folder

Comment: @SaadSohail so what am I doing wrong I have to do init.

Comment: no no npm init will bring all the required mean basic modules to use but if you want to use express then you have to use npm i or npm install to install that module

Answer (score 0):

So the command `npm init` will initialize a new project and generate a `package.json` file that contains project-related information. The command can be run anywhere. Use `npm init` when you want to create a new project of your own.

However, `npm install`, or `npm i` for short, will install project-related dependencies in the `package.json` file in an existing project directory. You can also use `npm i package_name_here` to install new package to your current project. The command must be run in an existing project directory with a valid `package.json`

Comment: that was not the case for me. I fixed the issue with change of cache path. Thanks.

Comment: I am glad that it's fixed